# $x=x_3v_1+(x_2-x_3)v_2+(x_1-x_2)v_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the basis $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $v_1=(1,1,1)$,$v_2=(1,1,0)$,$v_3=(1,0,0)$. Find a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(v_1)=(1,0),T(v_2)=(2,-1),\:\text{and}\:T(v_3)=(4,3)$, and compute $T(x)$ for $x=(2,-3,5)$.
>
> *Solution*: If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the expression for $x$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ is:
>
> $x=x_3v_1+(x_2-x_3)v_2+(x_1-x_2)v_3$
>
> By(Theorem 3)with
>
> $w_1=T(v_1)=(1,0),w_2=T(v_2)=(2,-1) \:\text{and}\: w_3=T(v_3)=(4,3)$
>
> we obtain
>
> $_T(x)=x_3v_1+(x_2-x_3)v_2+(x_1-x_2)v_3=x_3(1,0)+(x_2-x_3)(2,-1)+(x_1-x_2)(4,3)$
>
> In particular, if $x=(2,-3,5)$ we obtain $T(x)=(9,23)$

**1)** How do we get the expression $x=x_3v_1+(x_2-x_3)v_2+(x_1-x_2)v_3$? Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write the standard basis vectors ${e_1,e_2,e_3}$ in terms of those in S and note that $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$. As to why, you can now compute $T(x)$ knowing the $T(v_j)$.

Comment: @Paul I want to know where the expression $x=x_3v_1+(x_2-x_3)v_2+(x_1-x_2)v_3$ comes from. Using the $e_1,e_2,e_3$ I do not see as I can get it. S is the basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the transform sends it to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1e_1 + x_2e_2+x_3e_3$.

Since $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are three independent vectors in the 3-dimensional vector space $\Bbb R^3$, they form a basis, so any vectors, including $e_1, e_2, e_3$, can be expressed in terms of them. In general you could find these expressions by solving systems of linear equations, but in this case it is fairly easy to figure out that $$e_1 = v_3\\e_2 = v_2 - v_3\\e_3 = v_1 - v_2$$by inspection.

Now just substitute:
$$\begin{align}x &= x_1(v_3) + x_2(v_2 - v_3) + x_3(v_1 - v_2)\\&=x_3v_1 + (x_2 - x_3)v_2 + (x_1  - x_2)v_3\end{align}$$